# Lag when clicking on the autocomplete suggestion of a Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, lag, autosuggest

When I click on an autocomplete suggestion, there is always a tiny lag as you can see on the video.

[Demo Video](https://share.getcloudapp.com/P8u1zNDd)

This is a Windows Forms App and the code for the autocomplete is:

```
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        source.AddRange(new string[]
                    {           
                        "Eggs",
                        "Tomatoes",
                        "Milk",
                        "Apples",
                        "Bananas",
                        "Cheese",   
                    });

        product.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
        product.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        product.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

As you can see the data is hardcoded.

I'm using:

- Microsoft .NET Framework
- Version 4.8.04161
- Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA777
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2022
- ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495

Comment: Are you complaining about the long delay when the box is initially empty, or the few milliseconds it took for "tomatoes" to appear when you over typed "to"?

Comment: About the lag between the time I click on tomatoes and the time it is effectively selected.

Comment: Is it really the biggest problem in your to- do list? I can't believe the users will notice..